# Deploy Lumen app as a subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, router, lumen

I have deployed my Lumen app as a subdomain in a shared hosting server.

Folder structure ->

```
-public_html
 -api
-myapp
```

*(myapp is the folder where the lumen code sits)

in the public_html folder I have created a new folder under the name 'api'
and copied the myapp/public folder.

I have modified the public_html/api/index.php as

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../../myapp/bootstrap/app.php';

$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

the route php file (in the myapp folder - where the Lumen code is) looks like this ->

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
```

when browsing the homepage, get the error 'can't find page'

.htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

- If I create an index.html file and located it in the public_html/api I can see the content of the file.
  So, it feels like something wrong with the deployment of the Lumen app.

Comment: Do you get the 404 error from Lumen or from your webserver? Are there any other rewrites in `public_html` already that might interfere?

Comment: @TobiasK I am getting the 404 from the webserver. Actually, the public_html already has a Laravel public folder app. Maybe it is disturbing?

Comment: I think the deeper rewrites (api > public_html) get precedence, so it should be ok. Is routing working in the Laravel installation?

Comment: @TobiasK Yes, The Laravel site is online and all is working.

Comment: Are you serving this from nginx or Apache? Can you confirm that the `.htaccess` in `api` is read? E.g. make a syntax error in it and it should display an 500 error.

Comment: @TobiasK I am serving from Apache. Just did a syntax error and there was no 500 error. edited my question for the .htaccess syntax.

Comment: If the change did not cause an error you have to debug why the .htaccess file is not read. Most often this is due to a missing `AllowOverride` Directive, however you mention that Laravel in the parent directory works, so I have to rule this out.